# UIScrollView comes over UIImage in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm using storyboard and on my storyboard I've put a `UIScrollView` and `UIImage`, however as you can see in the image the `UIScrollView` comes over the `UIImage` but if you look at my storyboard it looks fine... Any idea how I can fix this or what the problem is?

[image]

`UIImageView` size inspector:

[image]

`UIScrollView` size inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but it looks like that image is actually taller than your `storyboard` allows.

is the `imageView.clipsToBounds == TRUE ?`

If not, you may want to set the `scrollView.frame`after you've set the image.

Comment: if(self.image.clipsToBounds == TRUE) doesn't return true

Comment: Then that's your problem. Set clip bounds on the storyboard.